# Display isn't changing like it should, but the code seems fine?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating a program that visualizes sorts, and my code seems to be fine. When I run it, though, it doesn't seem to update the GUI.

I've already tried validating and revalidating, and it does change the GUI, but it mostly just breaks it.

```
public void createWindow(Container win) {
        bars = new JPanel();
        bars.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c = new GridBagConstraints();

        startup = true;

        updateBars();

        startup = false;

        bars.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        bars.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 2, Color.BLACK));

        win.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        Dimension d2 = new Dimension(325, 250);
        bars.setPreferredSize(d2);
        bars.setMaximumSize(d2);
        bars.setSize(d2);
        win.add(bars, c);



        JPanel sorts = new JPanel();
        sorts.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        sorts.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 2, 2, 4, Color.BLACK));

        JLabel sortPrompt = new JLabel("Choose a sort: ");
        sortPrompt.setFont(sortPrompt.getFont().deriveFont(14.0f));
        sortPrompt.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        sorts.add(sortPrompt, c);

        String sortNames[] = {"Bogo Sort", "Gnome Sort", "Insertion Sort", "Slow sort"};
        JComboBox sortAlgs = new JComboBox(sortNames);
        sortAlgs.setFont(sortAlgs.getFont().deriveFont(14.0f));
        sortAlgs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sortChosen = (String)(sortAlgs.getSelectedItem());
                System.out.println(sortChosen);
            }
        });
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        sorts.add(sortAlgs, c);



        JLabel delayPrompt = new JLabel("Choose a delay time: ");
        delayPrompt.setFont(delayPrompt.getFont().deriveFont(13.0f));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        sorts.add(delayPrompt, c);

        String delays[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10", "25", "50", "100"};
        JComboBox delayTimes = new JComboBox(delays);
        delayTimes.setFont(delayTimes.getFont().deriveFont(13.0f));
        delayTimes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                delayTime = Integer.valueOf((String)(delayTimes.getSelectedItem()));
            }
        });
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        sorts.add(delayTimes, c);



        JButton start = new JButton("Start");
        start.setFont(start.getFont().deriveFont(16.0f));
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sortCompleted = 0;
                while (sortCompleted != 1) {
                    startBogoSort();
                }

            }
        });
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        sorts.add(start, c);

        JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
        stop.setFont(stop.getFont().deriveFont(16.0f));
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sortCompleted = 1;
            }
        });
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        sorts.add(stop, c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        Dimension d3 = new Dimension(250, 250);
        sorts.setPreferredSize(d3);
        win.add(sorts, c);

    }

    public void updateBars() {
        n = 10;
        arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr.add(i + 1);
        }
        if (startup == true) {
            Collections.shuffle(arr);
        }


        int maxHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            int height = arr.get(i);
            if (height > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = height;
            }
            int yPos = n - height * 20;
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.setBounds(i * 20, (yPos * 2) + ((height / 2) * 20), 20, height * 20);
            if (i == 0) {
                if (arr.get(i) > arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                } else if (arr.get(i) < arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
                }
            } else if (i == arr.size() - 1) {
                if (arr.get(i - 1) > arr.get(i)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                } else if (arr.get(i - 1) < arr.get(i)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                }
            } else {
                if (arr.get(i - 1) > arr.get(i) && arr.get(i) > arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                } else if (arr.get(i - 1) < arr.get(i) && arr.get(i) > arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                } else if (arr.get(i - 1) > arr.get(i) && arr.get(i) < arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
                } else if (arr.get(i - 1) < arr.get(i) && arr.get(i) < arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
                }
            }

            c.gridheight = height;
            c.ipadx = 20;
            c.ipady = height * 20;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
            c.gridy = n - height;
            bars.add(r, c);
        }
    }

    public void startBogoSort() {
        while (sortCompleted != 1) {
            int totalSize = arr.size() - 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < totalSize; i++) {
                if (arr.get(i - 1) > arr.get(i)) {
                    sortCompleted = 0;
                    i = totalSize + 1;
                } else {
                    sortCompleted = 1;
                }
            }

            if (sortCompleted == 0) {
                bars.removeAll();

                Collections.shuffle(arr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry for some of the mess, but it should show a panel with the bars that need sorting, and it should show it sorting the bars over time (the delay isn't implemented yet, but I should at least see the final result at this stage). What actually happens, though, is that it currently freezes up. Like I said previously, I have tried the validate() and revalidate() methods, but they just seemed to break the code further.

Comment: Please post [mcve]. ( It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem). Side note: you never change the layout manager of `sorts` so it uses the default one (`FlowLayout`)

Comment: `it currently freezes up` - so what debugging have you done? If it freezes up then you probably have an infinite loop. I see a bunch of while conditions. Have you added any display statements to see the value of your variables to determine if they ever change values? The GUI won't repaint itself until the looping logic finishes executing.

Comment: `but I should at least see the final result at this stage` - I don't see any logic that would do this. As far as I can see you have a method "updateBars()" that appears to add components to a panel, but that logic is only ever invoked once. So sorting will have no effect on the components added to the panel. `I've already tried validating and revalidating,` - you need to "revalidate()" the panel after adding/removing components on the panel.

Comment: I realized that my first mistake was trying to test this program out through the Bogo sort. I am currently working on coding out the Insertion sort, and I'll update this question.

Comment: Some things I see:  1. Your code never calls updateBars.  2.  startBogoSort is calling bars.removeAll.  3.  updateBars() always calls Collection.shuffle, so you will never see the results of your sorting.  You should use a model-view strategy:  updateBars should only modify the UI, and not modify data, while other methods should only modify data and should not modify the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake in this situation. I needed to create a new instance of GridBagConstraints and GridBagLayout in my updateBars() method. Plus, I used TimerTask and Timer to update the GUI. Turned out to be a much simpler solution than what I was originally thinking.

Here's my updated code:

```
public void createWindow(Container win) {
        bars = new JPanel();
        c = new GridBagConstraints();

        startup = true;

        updateBars();

        startup = false;

        bars.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        bars.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 2, Color.BLACK));

        win.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        bars.setBounds(0, 0, 325, 200);
        c.fill = c.VERTICAL;
        win.add(bars, c);





        JPanel sorts = new JPanel();
        sorts.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        sorts.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        sorts.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 2, 4, 4, Color.BLACK));

        JLabel sortPrompt = new JLabel("Choose a sort: ");
        sortPrompt.setFont(sortPrompt.getFont().deriveFont(15.0f));
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        sorts.add(sortPrompt, c);

        String sortNames[] = {"Bogo Sort", "Gnome Sort", "Insertion Sort", "Bubble Sort"};
        JComboBox sortAlgs = new JComboBox(sortNames);
        sortAlgs.setFont(sortAlgs.getFont().deriveFont(15.0f));
        sortAlgs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sortChosen = (String)(sortAlgs.getSelectedItem());
                System.out.println(sortChosen);
            }
        });
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        sorts.add(sortAlgs, c);



        JLabel delayPrompt = new JLabel("Choose a delay time: ");
        delayPrompt.setFont(delayPrompt.getFont().deriveFont(15.0f));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        sorts.add(delayPrompt, c);

        String delays[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10", "25", "50", "100", "500", "1000"};
        JComboBox delayTimes = new JComboBox(delays);
        delayTimes.setFont(delayTimes.getFont().deriveFont(15.0f));
        delayTimes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                delayTime = Integer.valueOf((String)(delayTimes.getSelectedItem()));
                System.out.println(delayTime);
            }
        });
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        sorts.add(delayTimes, c);



        JButton start = new JButton("Start");
        start.setFont(start.getFont().deriveFont(15.0f));
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sortCompleted = 0;
                if (sortChosen.equals(null)) {
                    sortChosen= "Bogo Sort";
                }

                if (sortChosen.equals("Bogo Sort")) {
                    startBogoSort();
                } else if (sortChosen.equals("Insertion Sort")) { 
                    startInsertionSort();
                } else if (sortChosen.equals("Bubble Sort")) {
                    startBubbleSort();
                } else if (sortChosen.equals("Gnome Sort")) {
                    System.out.println("This sort is not implemented yet");
                }

            }
        });
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        sorts.add(start, c);

        JButton shuffle = new JButton("Shuffle");
        shuffle.setFont(shuffle.getFont().deriveFont(15.0f));
        shuffle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TimerTask shuffleTask = new TimerTask () {
                    public void run() {
                        bars.removeAll();

                        Collections.shuffle(arr);

                        updateBars();
                        bars.revalidate();
                    }
                };

                Timer shuffler = new Timer();
                shuffler.schedule(shuffleTask, 10);

            }
        });
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        sorts.add(shuffle, c);

        JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
        stop.setFont(stop.getFont().deriveFont(15.0f));
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (sortChosen.equals("Bogo Sort")) {
                    bogo.cancel();
                    bogo.purge();
                } else if (sortChosen.equals("Bubble Sort")) {
                    bubble.cancel();
                    bubble.purge();
                }
            }
        });
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        sorts.add(stop, c);

        blank = new JLabel("      ");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        sorts.add(blank, c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        Dimension d3 = new Dimension(360, bars.getHeight());
        sorts.setPreferredSize(d3);
        win.add(sorts, c);

    }

    public void updateBars() {
        bars.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c = new GridBagConstraints();

        if (startup == true) {
            n = 10;
            arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr.add(i + 1);
            }
        }



        int maxHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            int height = arr.get(i);
            if (height > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = height;
            }
            int yPos = n - height * 20;
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.setBounds(i * 20, (yPos * 2) + ((height / 2) * 20), 20, height * 20);
            if (i == 0) {
                if (arr.get(i) > arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                } else if (arr.get(i) < arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
                }
            } else if (i == arr.size() - 1) {
                if (arr.get(i - 1) > arr.get(i)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                } else if (arr.get(i - 1) < arr.get(i)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                }
            } else {
                if (arr.get(i - 1) > arr.get(i) && arr.get(i) > arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                } else if (arr.get(i - 1) < arr.get(i) && arr.get(i) > arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                } else if (arr.get(i - 1) > arr.get(i) && arr.get(i) < arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
                } else if (arr.get(i - 1) < arr.get(i) && arr.get(i) < arr.get(i + 1)) {
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
                }
            }

            c.gridheight = height;
            c.ipadx = 20;
            c.ipady = height * 20;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
            c.gridy = n - height;
            bars.add(r, c);
        }
    }

public void startBogoSort() {
        if (delayTime == 0) {
            delayTime = 1;
        }

        TimerTask bogoTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                blank.setText("      ");

                for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                    if (arr.get(i - 1) > arr.get(i)) {
                        sortCompleted = 0;
                        i = arr.size() + 1;
                    } else {
                        sortCompleted = 1;
                    }
                }

                if (sortCompleted == 0) {
                    bars.removeAll();

                    Collections.shuffle(arr);

                    updateBars();
                    bars.revalidate();
                } else {
                    blank.setText("Sort Completed");
                    bogo.cancel();
                    bogo.purge();
                }
            }
        };


        bogo.scheduleAtFixedRate(bogoTask, 0, delayTime);
    }
```